# Multiple where clauses in select and insert

Tags: mysql, select, insert

So I have a 2 tables inside of the database.  The first is just a unique ID to name mapping

```
Customers
UID | CustomerName
```

In a second table I have something like the following

```
Orders
OrderNum | CustomerID | CustomerID2
```

Now I would like to insert into orders, but I only have the name of the 2 customer names, so I'm imagining something like the following (which doesnt work)

```
insert into Orders select null, UID as id1, UID as id2 from Customers where CustomerName=="sven";
```

How can I go about getting the two UID's from the first table?

Also I need to be able to do the reverse and select from the table

```
SELECT * FROM Orders a JOIN (Customers b) ON a.UID=b.UID WHERE b.CustomerName='sven'
```

Neither of these work, and I can't seem to find something similar online strangely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments if you're trying to insert two **different** customers' ids to one order you can do

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, CustomerID2)
SELECT c1.uid uid1, c2.uid uid2
  FROM
(
  SELECT uid 
    FROM customers
   WHERE customername = 'sven'
   LIMIT 1
) c1 CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT uid 
    FROM customers
   WHERE customername = 'jhon'
   LIMIT 1
) c2
```

To select an order where one of the customers exists

```
SELECT o.* 
  FROM orders o LEFT JOIN customers c1
    ON o.customerid = c1.uid LEFT JOIN customers c2
    ON o.customerid2 = c2.uid 
 WHERE c1.customername IN('sven', 'jhon')
    OR c2.customername IN('sven', 'jhon')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecbfe/2)** demo

**Original answer:** Are you looking for this?

To insert

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, CustomerID2)
SELECT c1.uid uid1, c2.uid uid2
  FROM customers c1 LEFT JOIN customers c2
    ON c1.customername = c2.customername
   AND c1.uid < c2.uid
 WHERE c1.customername = 'sven'
 LIMIT 1
```

To select

```
SELECT o.* 
  FROM orders o LEFT JOIN customers c1
    ON o.customerid = c1.uid LEFT JOIN customers c2
    ON o.customerid2 = c2.uid 
 WHERE c1.customername = 'sven'
    OR c2.customername = 'sven'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbd7/6)** demo

Comment: Indeed this works great! I wouldn't have thought to use a cross join between multiple selects.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To insert into one table from another table use [this syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

So in your case your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, CustomerID2)
SELECT UID, UID
  FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName = 'sven';
```

If you want to insert multiple record from a single query you can use `IN` operator instead of `=` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, CustomerID2)
SELECT UID, UID
  FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName IN ('sven', 'smith');
```

There is a mistake in your join in the `SELECT` query:

You joined both tables with `UID` while there is no `UID` in `Orders` table. May be you mean `CustomerID`. Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders a 
  JOIN Customers b 
    ON a.CustomerID = b.UID 
 WHERE b.CustomerName='sven'
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce54e/1)

Comment: So the problem with this insert is that CustomerID and CustomerID2 need to be different.  One of them will refer to 'sven', but the other lets say 'juan' should have a separate UID.